# Why i got negative value for volume?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the indicated volumes under the surface $z=\frac{1}{y+2}$ and over the area bounded by $y=x$ and $y^2+x=2$. After sketching the graph for $x=2-y^2$, and $x=y$ i found that $y=0$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$ (the image shown below)

[image: the graph for given boundaries]

so find for the indicated volume

> $V=\int _{y=0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int _{x=2-y^2}^y\left(\frac{1}{y+2}\right)dxdy=\int _0^{\sqrt{2}}\left(y-1\right)dy$

yields $V=1-\sqrt{2}=-0.414213562$

Why i got negative value for volume? Or is there something wrong with my calculation? Is it because i used the wrong values for the boundaries? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: In your double integral, for $y=0$, the lower bound $x=2-y^2=2$ is higher than your upper bound $y=0$. I'd say you have an area parametrization issue

Comment: Double integral gives you an area, you need to find volume, so should be triple integral. Let along correct bounds for each of the iterated integrals.

Comment: get it, the answer becomes $\sqrt{2}-1$ so this time the value is positive. What i found is the value for the area not volume? @AlexH.

Comment: If a 1D integral gives you the area below the curve, certainly a 2D integral will give you the volume below the surface.

Comment: Note that I didn't comment on the result itself. I'm not even sure I understand what the $(x,y)$ area should be. Is it the one below $y=x$ our above it?

Comment: $y=x$ is the boundary below the plane $z=\frac{1}{y+2}$, sir. I think what i found is the volume below the surface of this plane, isn't it? @AlexH.

Comment: Your two equations of the type $f(x,y)=0$ define the borders of the projection of your volume on the plane $x=0, y=0$, right? That's what you plotted on your chart. The problem is this definition is ambiguous, you need to add a 3rd border/equation to define this area clearly. If you look at your chart, you'll see that your two curves could indicate two areas, one delimited by $y=0$ (the one above $y=z$) and one by $x=0& (resp. below).

Comment: you're so right that my curves indicate two areas, since the equivalent integral (if it's correct) has the limits from $y=x$ to $y=\sqrt{2-x}$ and $x=0$ to $x=2$. How to add that 3rd border? @AlexH.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex H. said,
the inner integral
should be from
$y$ to
$2-y^2$.
You have the reverse.

Making this change
will 
change the sign of your result.

If you look at your plot,
you show that
$2-y^2$
is above $y$.